# Awake – a cryptic crossword

Tags: cryptic-crosswords

This crossword is a tribute to the 1994 album *Awake* by Dream Theater.<sup>1</sup> No knowledge of the music itself is required for solving.

Some clues are missing a part which has been replaced by two question marks (**??**). Before solving, each of these must be filled with a different track title from the album. Tracks are listed below.

> 6:00
> Caught in a Web
> Innocence Faded
> Erotomania
> Voices
> The Silent Man
> The Mirror
> Lie
> Lifting Shadows Off a Dream
> Scarred
> Space-Dye Vest

[image]

**Across**
1. Kaylee finally embraced by excited Dr. Tam, as fantasised (6)
5. Death Eaters circling furnace? (6)
10. Natural growth place for amateur philosopher shunned by clubs? (3,4)
11. Flowers from moon allowed to be described by empty **??** (7)
12. Defilement of broken tail during **??** examination's concluding part (9)
13. He was killed by Ray Charles's heart breaking – "I claim victory!" (5)
15. Islamic State's units devastated Iraq regularly (7)
18. Draw in breath of air, perhaps quietly (4)
19/30d. British paper, at that time, describing retired American (3,3)
21. At first mention assisting **??** from Sweden? (4)
23. Novel, extremely artful uniform queen maybe returned (7)
26. Oxygen accompanied by harsh smell (5)
27. Having partial separation into two opposing parts like a pizzly bear? (9)
29. See opposite swapping vicious extremities (7)
31. Frame of genuine old Android reveals location info (7)
32. Keitel gutted, **??** and chain (6)
33. Frightened and **??** after loss of 2 down (6)

**Down**
2. Italian city boy, at heart? (5)
3. Jack, having escaped Indonesian island, smears pictures (7)
4. Kill insect eating new veranda's bottom (9)
5. Bear seen near northern retreat (5)
6. Taking delight in piece of jewellery after a social function (7)
7. She met Wall-E in **??**, essentially (3)
8. **??** finally, leaving teen diva confused (7)
9. Pose like an ace (5)
14. Areas made uniform, clean up a form of martial arts (5)
16. Exemplary European leader entered military alliance (5)
17. Again hurts son, e.g., **??** (9)
20. Pacific Islander unchanged in **??** (7)
22. Gory content spoken, supported by backer of brothers – and of sisters (7)
24. Jar of soup placed in a medium-sized Rioja case (7)
25. Drive back in the grips of **??** (5)
27. Covering for female alien (5)
28. **??** about article describing tropical plant (5)
30. (*See 19 across*)

<sub><sup>1</sup> In case this sounds familiar, the exact same idea was the basis of an [earlier crossword](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/105134/six-directions-of-cryptic-cluebulence). And before you ask: No, I have no intention of covering the band's entire discography this way.</sub>

Comment: I REALLY loved this one jafe, you had some excellent nonstandard wordplays in there that I really loved...once I figured them out :-)

Comment: @JeremyDover Glad to hear it!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Grid:

> [image: Grid]
>  Notice also the top row spelling out Dream Theater (thanks to Jeremy Dover for pointing that out!)

Clues (Thanks to Jeremy Dover for providing the wordplay for 27A!)

> [image: Clues]

Comment: Ninja'd! The wordplay for 27A is rot13(N cvmmyl orne vf unys cbyne/unys tevmmyl, fb vg jbhyq or FRZVCBYNE. Vg'f n chaal qqrs.) Nice job!

Comment: Might also want to mention the easter egg up top...

Comment: @JeremyDover Ah, thanks that makes sense! Thanks also for pointing out the easter egg, I would have completely missed it.